# Stopping Sitecore application for server fixes

Tags: sql-database, infrastructure

We got recommendation from Infra team for disk host cache configuration change on Sitecore SQL database servers. Basically change is Disk host caching should be read\write for OS, read\only for data and none for log disks and application shouldn't write on disk which means we need to stop IIS for CM and CD sites. Along with this we also need to stop xconnect collection, marketing ,refdata , xconnect collection search websites so that these sites shouldn't write anything to xDB while Infra activity is being progressed.

Do you think stopping and starting these IIS websites is okay OR this activity leads to unexpected issues since this is complete XP system and all these components are connected to each other.

Version: Sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 1):

Your site will be inaccessible during maintenance and usually, it is recommended to stop/restart IIS out of working hours when almost no one uses your site. *Existing data should not be lost*, but site visitors will lose connection during some action (form submission etc.) and Sitecore analytics will not be triggered.

If you need to stop your sites, then, usually, it is recommended to stop XP instances first (CD instances first, then CM), then you can stop xConnect instances, and then after maintenance, you can start xConnect instances first and then XP instances (CM first, then CD instances).

Comment: thank you Alexander so basically sequence is very much important for functioning all components properly after start